# Memory warning debugging in instruments

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, instruments

I am new to ios development. I am having a very serious issue now. My application is almost complete but it crashes very often due to memory warning. The memory warning is received whenever I present a new view controller on the top of the existing view controller. The custom view class adds UIWebView to its view when the new view controller is loaded.

I tried to debug the memory allocation with instruments but do not have any idea on how the memory is being allocated. The screenshot of the heapshot analysis shows bunch of non-objects as in the figure below and when I see the stack trace it points to adding the webview.
[image]

Please suggest me how I have to debug. What does these non-objects point to and how should I deal with them. I thank you for your suggestion and help in advance.

Comment: Press Command-option-r in xcode.  Is "Enable Zombie Objects" checked?  If so, try unchecking that.

Comment: I disabled the zombie objects but still the result is almost the same. The application still receives the memory warning and I have the similar type of non objects as above. What may be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-object allocations are almost always used as backing stores within objects.  I.e. an NSMutableArray will often be backed by several malloc()'d buffers that show up in non-object allocations in instruments.

Unless the non-objects are the *only* thing showing up as allocations in Instruments, you can ignore them.

Instead, focus on allocations of a specific type.   Anything else in that Heapshot iteration? Looks like there is a CardScrollView in that backtrace on the right.  Are they going away correctly?

Comment: I feel CardScrollView is the problem here. It is just a custom class with a weak pointer in the main view controller. But I have this view set to nil in viewDidUnload method. This UIView also adds UIWebview to itself which in turns loads some local html file. I dont see any problem here.

Comment: Well... if it loads a UIView/UIWebView and those don't ever go away, that's a problem.   Are you doing fully iterative heapshot analysis?  

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/